# Excel 365: RibbonX command to "Show Quick Access Toolbar"

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

My Excel 365 VBA application adds Undo and Redo to QAT by RibbonX:

```html
<qat>
     <documentControls> 
         <control idMso="Undo" imageMso="Undo"/> 
         <control idMso="Redo" imageMso="Redo"/> 
     </documentControls>
 </qat>
```

Recently Microsoft adapted the Ribbon interface:

[image]

How can I grant within XLM or VBA that "Show Quick Access Toolbar" is set?

Comment: Why don't you just add your buttons to the ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon and QAT settings are stored in officeUI-files and officeSL-files in the following folder;

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office
```

The officeUI-files are used for storing the customizations of the Classic Ribbon and the officeSL-files are used for storing the customizations of the Single Line Ribbon of Office 365.

So, your code can check whether any UI customizations are saved to the mentioned above folder. The Ribbon UI doesn't provide any APIs for checking that.

Also you may try to use the [CommandBars.GetVisibleMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.getvisiblemso) method which returns `True` if the control identified by the `idMso` parameter is visible.

But I'd suggest placing a custom UI on the ribbon instead, not QAT.